# Fragment in Viewpager2 has an activity but context is null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity with a ViewPager2 which handles 3 fragments like this:

```
class ViewPagerActivity : FragmentActivity {

    private val firstFragment by lazy { FirstFragment.newInstance() }
    private val secondFragment by lazy { SecondFragment.newInstance() }
    private val thirdFragment by lazy { ThirdFragment.newInstance() }
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
        val pagerAdapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(this)
        binding.pager.adapter = pagerAdapter
        binding.pager.offscreenPageLimit = 2
        binding.pager.setCurrentItem(1, false)
        binding.pager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {

            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int
            ) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels)
                // DO some stuff
            }

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state)
                if (state == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    // DO some other things
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The first fragment implements the following abstract fragment:

```
abstract class ScannerFragment(val type: VisionType): Fragment() {

    lateinit var viewFinder: PreviewView

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        if (activity != null || isAdded) {
            viewFinder.post {
                startCamera()
            }
        }
    }

    @AfterPermissionGranted(REQ_CAMERA_PERMISSION)
    fun startCamera() {
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) && context != null) {

            // Start the camera
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a lot of crashes in `startCamera()` when calling `requireContext()` which for some reason is null. And all the crashes comes only when the `startCamera()` is called from `onViewCreated`, but the `activity` is not `null` or it has been added to the activity. In both those cases, how can the context in this case be null?

My guess is that the crash happens sometimes when the app comes back from the background, but I have never been able to reproduce it myself.

Is there a better way to handle the fragments in the activity so they are correctly recreated/added if needed?

Comment: I had a similar issue before, and recovered by posting some delay before using the context.. Try to do that in `startCamera()`

Comment: That's why I have the call in post {} of a view. Do you think I need to wait even longer?

Comment: Not sure if `post` does a sufficient delay, it ensure that it's on the main thread instead.. You probably can use `handler.postDelayed` with something like 100 millsec